How to iniialize materialize css in my node project to use sidenav
I am working on a nodeJs app which has a main secssion. Within the main secssion i have a partial secssion called _header. I want to use materialize css in my app to bring a sidenav. But i am not able to intialize materialize css.
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        const sidenav = document.querySelector('.sidenav');
        M.Sidenav.init(sidenav);
        });
</script>

This does not work.
